# Kubernetes documentation search is not working fine

Tags: documentation

i observed a major cosmetic change happened to Kubernetes documentation recently, before to that search option was pretty good. Now, it’s not working fine

If I type “security context” or “resource requests” in the search box, in the results, it is showing “fetching results….”, no result even after 15 minutes waiting also.

It works with single words like “security” and “resources” like that, but results[image] are not specific. Please help and suggest.

Comment: The kubernetes.io website update is terrible. Please report a bug at https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/21808

Comment: It happens to me with Firefox. If you try another browser or even a new private window on firefox it will work. Deleting cookies for the specific type didn't help either.

Comment: @DimiDak, thanks for the cue. I deleted the cookies on Firefox 119.0 (Windows) and issue is resolved for now. A clean Chrome did not have the issue to begin with. (Adblocking was indifferent for anyone reading this in the future.)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure this is a right question here? Is sounds just like a complain.
But anyway, take a screenshot. Everything works fine right now

[image]